# Different URL for different variaion of a variable product in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am facing a problem with woocommerce.

I am selling books with woocommerce and have a store in amazon too.
For the books in my web store I have two buying options - 1. Ebook, 2- Paperback.

I have added a Variable product and customized with attributes and variations.

But I want users to be redirected when they choose paperback option to Amazon link. For ebooks they can pay and download from my store.

I am not finding any options in woocommerce. Can anyone please help me?

Thanks